# Stretch table column in Reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I'm trying to stretch a table column in Reportlab (not RML), I've tried setting colWidths like this:

```
tab = Table(data, colWidths=["*", None, None, None, None, None])
```

as written in the documentation, but the size of the first column doesn't change (it stays on "size-to-contents"). Is there any way to make the first column stretch to available space, without specifying a fixed size? (since the other columns *will* change dynamically depending on some parameters)

Comment: The available space will change depending on some parameters as well? Why you can't use a variable to set the size of the first column?

Comment: I can't use a variable to set the size of the first column because I don't want to set the size of the first column, I want it to just resize to whatever space is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a deliberate behavior of Reportlab, since the width calculation code says this:

```
def _calc_pc(V,avail):
    '''check list V for percentage or * values
    1) absolute values go through unchanged
    2) percentages are used as weights for unconsu
    3) if no None values were seen '*' weights are
    set equally with unclaimed space
    otherwise * weights are assigned as None'''
```

Which means that `*` and `None` can't be used together in the list of widths, which doesn't make sense because then how do you make a column stretch while the other are sized to content. Anyways, I ended up writting a wrapper function that re-calculates everything:

```
def table_fix(data, cols, total):
    table = Table(data, colWidths=cols)
    res = list(cols)
    val = table._cellvalues
    style = table._cellStyles
    while None in res:
        idx = res.index(None)
        width = 0
        for i, vi in enumerate(val):
            v = vi[idx]
            s = style[i][idx]
            nw = table._elementWidth(v, s) + s.leftPadding + s.rightPadding
            if nw > width:
                width = nw
        res[idx] = width
    table._colWidths = table._argW = res
    return table
```

Ugly but does the job for me. It can be extended to support multiple `*` columns if need be.